# Global regularity theory for unbounded domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I have seen that, if $f \in L^2 (\Omega)$ with $\Omega$ bounded and regular then if $u$ solves $- \Delta u =f$ in $H^1_0 (\Omega)$, then $u \in H^2$. This is standard regularity theory.  I've also seen that these arguments work, in general, if $f \in L^2 _{loc} $ and $u \in H^1 _{loc}$, and the thesis would be that $u \in H^2 _{loc}$, where this time the domain can be unbounded.

My question is: does global regularity also hold for unbounded domains? For instance, $f \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $u \in H^1 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ solves the previous equation, then do I have $u \in H^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$? Or do I only have $ u \in H^2 _{loc} (\mathbb{R}^n)$?

I have a feeling that this is true, and it could be proved by contradiction, but I wanted to ask before attempting to prove something false.

Also, if the thing above is true, does it also hold for global $L^p$ regularity? Do you have any suggested reference where thsese facts are proved? (if true, of course)

Comment: I would imagine that $D^2 u \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ is possible, but $u, Du \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ is not. The reason is that the Sobolev embedding (on $\mathbb{R^n}$) only works for the exponent $2^* = \frac{2n}{n-2}$. So I would also expect that $D u \in L^{2^*}(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $u \in L^{2^{**}}(\mathbb{R^n})$ are possible.

Comment: But $u, Du \in L^2 (\mathbb{R}^n)$ is an hypothesis. I get a solution in $H^1$ thanks to, say, a direct method approach

Comment: Oh, I missed this. Then I think that $D^2 u \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ should be OK. Although, I worry about the direct method approach in this context, for the very same reason I mentioned above.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Actually I don't really use the direct method for obtaining a solution in $H^1$, and my actual problem isn't even the one I've written, I just have some doubts regarding regularity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your background, I would try one of the two:

1. Recover second order derivatives of $u$ by applying [Riesz transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_transform#Relationship_with_the_Laplacian) to $f$. One uses Fourier transform to justify that Riesz transforms are bounded operators on $L^2$.
2. Apply integration by parts twice: $\int \partial_{ii} u \partial_{jj} u = \int \partial_{ij} u \partial_{ij} u$. This shows that $\int |\Delta u|^2 = \int |D^2 u|^2$.

In both cases, one needs to check some details related to regularity of $u$ (or rather lack thereof) and the sense in which derivatives are taken.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Or, at least, I can't see why you should be wrong. Actually my problem is quite different, the question was just an oversemplification. But I think I got it, I should check the details but it seems to work. Stay tuned, I might ask the "real" question soon!